# firebase callback function is not getting called if there is any error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to set my data in cloud function using `firebase-admin` module. I have added callback function to handle the error. But if any one of property value is 'undefined', it throws the error in log

```
Error : Firebase.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property
```

I am expecting that firebase should call my callback function. Should I use `try-catch` to handle such kind of scenarios?

```
return admin.database().ref('mypath').set({
 prop1 : value1,
 prop2 : value2
}, function (error){
        console.log('got the error ', error);
        if(error){
            setErroneousRecord(row, index);
        } else {
            successfulRecords++;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: @camden_kid added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like either `value1` or `value2` is `undefined`, which is not allowed and the client/SDK detects that and rejects the write.

The Firebase error callback is only called for a server-side failure, so when the Firebase security rules reject the write operation.